# Upgrade to Tensorflow 1.4 in Datalab

Tags: tensorflow, upgrade, google-cloud-datalab

Does anyone know how to update Tensorflow 1.2 in an existing Datalab image, to Tensorflow 1.4?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We should have an update in the new year, so this won't be necessary at some point.

In the meantime, does a regular `pip install` work. You'll likely need the `--upgrade` flag to install over the pre-installed 1.2 version.